# начать работать со следующим блоком json если текущий не существует ('NoneType' object is not subscriptable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, json

Начну из того, что получается, это тестовый запрос где в структуре json существует каждый блок, и все лежит близко:

```
def main(request):
    req = requests.get('https://d3.ru/api/posts').json()
    arr = []
    for data in req['posts']:
        urls = data['main_image_url']
        if urls != None:
            arr.append(urls)
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'arr': arr})
```

Дальше, я начинаю углубляться в структуру json :

```
def main(request):
    req = requests.get('https://d3.ru/api/posts').json()
    arr = []
    for data in req['posts']:
        urls = data['data']['media']['thumbnails']['original']['url']
        if urls is not None:
            arr.append(urls)
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'arr': arr})
```

Но выдает ошибку `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`, насколько я понимаю, этот блок существует не у всех элементов, или проблема в чем то другом? Если всё так как я думаю, то как начать обрабатывать следующий блок если этот не существует?

К сожалению json разместить тут не могу, он слишком длинный.

Comment: Вам придется добавлять проверки через if, например: `if data['data'] and data['data']['media'] and ...` и проверять так. Либо, обернуть всю конструкцию и ловить исключение try/except'ом. `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable,` означает что `[]` были вызваны для None. Попробуйте: `None['data']` / `None[0]`. Кст, а как вы в вопросе форматировали код?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, как я добавил серый фон к коду?) Если да, то при выделении нужного куска клацаете на панели инструментов на скобки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce

path = ('data', 'media', 'thumbnails', 'original', 'url')
val = reduce(lambda c, k: c[k] if c is not None and k in c else None, path, data)
```

Comment: О, интересно выглядит!

Comment: @gil9red сейчас появится jfs и расскажет почему это плохое решение :)

Comment: ого, а можете в двух словах объяснить что тут произошло, и вообще легально ли это). А то за лямбда-выражения ни одним глазом не брался)

Comment: @Romikromikromik функция [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) последовательно вызывает лямбду для каждого элемента в кортеже `path`, передавая ей элемент кортежа и результат предыдущего вызова лямбды. Соответственно, на первом вызове из data извлекается элемент с ключом `data` и передаётся во второй вызов, на втором вызове из этого элемента извлекается элемент с ключом `media` и передаётся в третий вызов и т.д. Если на одном из вызовов элемент с нужным ключом не будет найден, будет возвращён `None`.

Comment: Спасибо! На досуге про лямбды почитаю.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать через модуль [dpath](https://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python):

```
# pip install dpath
import dpath.util


data_1 = {
    'data': {
        'media': None
    }
}

urls = dpath.util.values(data_1, "data/media/thumbnails/original/url")
print(urls)  # []


data_2 = {
    'data': {
        'media': {
            'thumbnails': {
                'original': {
                    'url': [
                        'http://...',
                        'https://...',
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

urls = dpath.util.values(data_2, "data/media/thumbnails/original/url")
print(urls)  # [['http://...', 'https://...']]
```

---

Или сделать какой-нибудь самописный [аналог](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7320664/5909792):

```
# SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7320664/5909792
def xpath_get(mydict, path):
    elem = mydict
    try:
        for x in path.strip("/").split("/"):
            elem = elem.get(x)
    except:
        pass

    return elem


urls = xpath_get(data_1, "data/media/thumbnails/original/url")
print(urls)  # None


urls = xpath_get(data_2, "data/media/thumbnails/original/url")
print(urls)  # ['http://...', 'https://...']
```